# Initialize my list from the backend when building for the first time

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of `Contact` objects that I display within a ListView. What I'd like to do is to initialize my list from the backend when the page builds for the first time.

[image]

I get the data from the backend with the ScopedModel.
So what I tried to do is :

```dart
ScopedModelDescendant<Account>(
        builder: (context, child, _account){
... 

if(_account.profile.contacts != null)
   _account.profile.contacts.forEach((contact){
       Contacts contactToAdd = new Contacts(contact.name, contact.label, contact.phonenumber,contact.email);
       contactToAdd.onTap = editContact(contactToAdd);
       listOfContact.add(contactToAdd);
    });
  }
)
```

But the problem is, as the code is in the `build method`, every time I add a contact, everythings build because of the ScopedModel and this code is re-executed Making that every time I add one contact, the whole list is added again which duplicates and multiplies a lot of things.

Why don't I execute this code outside of the Build method, in a `didChangeDependencies()` for exemple ? Because I need the datas of the Scoped Model (account) to make my test.

So I have no idea how to proceed :/ Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BloC pattern, it will retrieve the info only once.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-oneyearchallenge-scoped-model-vs-bloc-pattern-vs-states-rebuilder-23ba11813a4f